# Ruby on Rails, require old password to change password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have implemented a user authentication system in rails using the  gem 'bcrypt';I would like to insert a current password field to the edit form to make the changes to the password.
How can do this?

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
  before_create :create_remember_token
 
  #Associations
  has_one :profile
  has_many :posts

  #validations
  validates :name, presence: true, length:  {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format:  {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
  
  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
  
  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private 
    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end
  
end
```

```html
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>



      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view file:

```
  <%= f.label :current_password %>
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
```

Also make sure you permit the current_password parameter in your controller.

I assumed current_password attr is already defined by has_secured_password.